# jquery mobile not working with IE and FF

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-mobile

i try to execute jquery mobile in IE and FF but i have a blank page:
i will diplay a first image issue from a servlet and i have a link that let me to dispaly all page:
this s my code for the div:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pf<%= sIdPF %>" class="pageThumbnail pfType<%= sIdPFType %>" data-theme="c">
<div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <%= sDocumentName%>
        <span style="font-size:0.8em;"><%= sPageCount %></span>
    </div>
```

div for the first image and sTn is the url to the servlet:
        ');" data-download="<%= sURLDownload %>">

div for the other image,the id butAddOther let me to display other image

```
    <div class="otherImages"></div>
<div class="paginateToolBar" data-pagecount="<%= iPageCount %>" data-pagecountrest="<%= iPageCount-1 %>"  style="text-align:center;<%=(bShowPagination?"":"display:none;") %>">
    <a href="#"  id="butAddOther">suivant</a>
</div>
```

can anyone say why image is getting displayed in chrome but not in FF and IE